# Finding Edge cases to test

Tags: python, testing

I am trying to find the minimum number of steps it takes to reach "1" with the following:

For each step, I can take one of the following steps:

1. I can add "1"
2. I can subtract "1"
3. I can divide by "2"

The function will be passed a string representing a positive integer. My function appears to be working but I am failing on some edge cases, but I am not sure how to find the edge cases that would cause a failure.

```
n = int(n)
count = 0

while n > 1:
    if int(n) & int(n-1) == 0:
        count += len(str(bin(n))) - 3
        break
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n /= 2
    else:
        if (n - 1) % 4 == 0:
            n -= 1
        else:
            n += 1
    count += 1
return count
```

Here are a couple of examples of passed tests:

**Input:** solution.solution('15')
**Output:**  5
(15 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1)

**Input:** solution.solution('4')
**Output:** 2
(4 -> 2 -> 1)

Comment: Which edge cases? Add a test input to your post so we can check where you went wrong.

Comment: You also seem to be failing on 23 with a TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. You should probably change the n /= 2 to n = int(n/2). And your break condition is a little obscure:)

Comment: @usr2564301 - I am not sure what edge cases are failing as they are hidden (this is part of a coding challenge). I have been testing it using a spreadsheet, but there is a limit to what I can do with a spreadsheet

Comment: @SinanKurmus  - You found my glitch! Thank you so much. My obscure break was hiding the loop I was creating when I reached n=3. The code looped up and added a step when it should have continued down.  Thanks!

Comment: A better fix is to keep using `int`s throughout: `n //= 2` or `n >>= 1`. After your first `n = int(n)` you do not need any more casts.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a naive solution and compare the results for a bunch of inputs.

```
def elliott(n):
    n = int(n)
    count = 0

    while n > 1:
        if int(n) & int(n-1) == 0:
            count += len(str(bin(n))) - 3
            break
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n //= 2
        else:
            if (n - 1) % 4 == 0:
                n -= 1
            else:
                n += 1
        count += 1
    return count

def naive(n):
    reached = {int(n)}
    steps = 0
    while 1 not in reached:
        for x in reached.copy():
            reached |= {x - 1, x + 1}
            if x % 2 == 0:
                reached.add(x // 2)
        steps += 1
    return steps

for n in range(1, 20):
    x, y = elliott(n), naive(n)
    if x != y:
        print(n, x, y)
```

Output:

```
3 3 2
6 4 3
11 6 5
12 5 4
13 6 5
```